# How to Generate an "publishsettings" file

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I want to deploy my website to Sitecore Azure, inside Install management certificate On Sitecore Azure it is written that,

'Generate an "publishsettings" file which automatically installs a management certificate on your subscription by following this link(https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx/).'

But the link is not working. How to proceed?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is outdated. Please use the following link to generate Microsoft Azure *.publishsettings file. You must have active Microsoft Azure Subscription assigned to your Microsoft Account or Work/School Account (aka Corp Account):

1. The latest schema version (currently 2.0) - https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index
2. Shema version 1.0 - https://manage.windowsazure.com/PublishSettings/index?client=&schemaVersion=1.0

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I have uploaded the publish-setting file, now its showing wait icon and Start, Suspend, cancel options, but Start and Suspend options are disabled. whats the next step, please suggest?

Comment: Could you please attach the image of Sitecore Azure application to shows where you get stuck in.